# XML parsing with column and value

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net

I need to parse an XML file. I am very new to parsing the document. I am using XMLReader to parse the document.Part of the XML document looks like below:

```
<TABLE>
   <TR>
      <TH>NCOL</TH>
      <TD>Col2</TD>
      <TD>Col3</TD>
      <TD>Col4</TD>
      <TD>Col5</TD>
      <TD>Col6</TD>
      <TD>Col7</TD>
   </TR>
   <TR>
      <TH>3245</TH>
      <TD>Testing</TD>
      <TD />
      <TD>45678-9876</TD>
      <TD />
      <TD />
      <TD />
   </TR>
</TABLE>
```

Is there any way, I can associate column name with the value  so I was wondering while parsing the document I can find out that 3245 is associated with NCOL and Testing is associated with Col2 and Col3 is empty.

Comment: Count your columns.  Just like you are already doing manually.  you can tell that the first empty column corresponds with `Col3` because they both occur third.

Comment: I was going to do that, but thought there might be a better way. I am very new to XML parsing so may be there is some better way.

Comment: Side note: your XML looks like HTML. Make sure it is not the case and indeed the document is always valid XML.

Comment: Usually one starts with DOM level parser (`XDocument`/LINQ-to-XML or `XmlDocument`) before going to lower level parsing with `XmlReader`. Please comment on why do you need to use `XmlReader`.

Comment: Like I mentioned before, I am new to XML parsing. Actually this is my first XML document that I am parsing. I goggled and found out XMLReader to parse the XML document.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, trying to parse html (pretending it's XML) is not a good idea. But the essence of your question may still be useful for parsing actual XML.

I've never done linq in VB.Net, but this might set you on the right path. It takes the xml, treats the first row as header elements and creates a dictionary>:

```
dim xml = XElement.Parse('the xml string")
```

Or

```
dim xml = XElement.Load("your file")
dim items = xml.Elements("TR").FirstOrDefault().Elements() _
    .Select(Function(x, i)New with{ .Index = i, .Xml = x }) _
    .ToDictionary(Function(x) x.Xml.Value, Function(x) xml.Elements("TR").Skip(1) _
                                        .SelectMany(Function(e) e.Elements()) _
                                        .GroupBy(Function(y) y.Parent) _
                                        .Select((Function(y) y.Key.Elements()(x.Index).Value)))
```